# Кэш Entity Framework не сбрасывается

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

При вызове из метода контроллера метода

```
public IEnumerable<Client> GetAllTest()
{
    var clients = _db.Clients.AsNoTracking().ToArray();
    return rep.Get();
}
```

я получаю клиентов - актуальное состояние таблицы БД.

если этот метод вызвать из юнит теста (проверяю его) - clients уже другие - состояние таблицы на тот момент, когда я экспериментрировал с клиентами чуть ранее - удалял-добавлял их.

Видимо в тестах срабатывает кэш, хотя AsNoTracking() запрещает изпользовать кэш. Почему это происходит и как от этого избавиться?

UPD
Выяснил, что этот эффект происходит не обязательно при вызове метода из тестового, а вообще из любого другого проекта в данном солюшне.

Comment: а вы точно к одной и той же БД цепляетесь?

Comment: да, к база одна и та же

Comment: а почему вы для каждого теста не хотите заново создавать контекст данных?

Comment: я не знаю. так правильно?

Comment: ну и вы не забывали сохранить изменения в БД после того, как добавляли/удаляли данные?

Comment: юнит тесты по идее должны быть независимы, то есть все, что надо для юнит теста, создавайте в юнит тесте.

Comment: я удалял-добавлял строки в таблицу прямыми sql запросами, соотв. SaveChages() не вызывал, может в это дело? (тестирую)

Comment: Выполнил такой код:

_db.Clients.Remove(_db.Clients.Find(1));
_db.SaveChanges();

- не помогло